# Area 51 showing wrong score/old name for Stack Overflow account

Tags: support, reputation, area-51, network-profile

I am having a reputation of 2042 reputatin points on Stack Overflow, but when I visit [Area 51](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange#History), it's showing the wrong score.

> (adding 162 of Area51 score)

[My Area 51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/87976/yoga)

Please see the attached image:

> [image]

**Edit 2:** The name/profile picture is showing up wrong (the old one), but I updated my name long time back, only Area 51 is showing up the old one.

Comment: But isn't your name on stackoverflow [Anirban N](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1512940/anirban-n)? CodingAnt is the user who proposed Yoga.

Comment: @royhowie yup , that too seems bug , I used to have this name long time back, but why it is still showing up here , I dont know !

Comment: You should probably add that to your question. I didn't realize what you said until I found the area51 proposal, clicked on CodingAnt, then navigated to your network profile.

Comment: Added mate , i should be more careful in future :)

Answer (score 3):

No bug here.

The Area 51 "user card" showing the user name, reputation points, and badges, is doing a **sum** of all the user's accounts having 200+ rep *plus the Area 51 account itself*.

In your case you have only Stack Overflow and Area 51:

> [image]

2052 + 161 = 2213 so next question is: why is the card showing only 2203? Where are the missing 10 points? And the answer for this is caching: while the accounts list is real-time (maybe with few minutes cache), the card is cached for about a full day i.e. recalculating the reputation and badges only on daily basis. Since you got upvote on Stack Overflow today, it's not yet reflected in the card.

This assumption can be verified by another example, [the user](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/104774/suresh-kamrushi) who started [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86022/yoga) - very similar to your case.

Comment: 10 is misssing , because after posting this question my reputation gott elevated by 10 :)

Comment: No, I explained it clearly - the cache can last even a day. If tomorrow it will still show 2203 then it's a bug.

Comment: I am not saying its an bug, just to let you know that after posting my reputation got incresed